# Cognito & Two Factor Authentication

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, two-factor-authentication, authy

Is there any available SDK of Twilio or Authy to use for Two Factor Authentication with Cognito?

Or What are the best practices to do User Authentication via Cognito with Two Factor Authentication?

Basically how mobile app authenticate user with Two Factor Authentication by using Cognito for Identity Management?

Comment: Could you explain how do you want to use 2fa with Cógnito, please?

Comment: I want to use 2FA as the approach of "Whatsapp", user sign up with Mobile Number, they get authentication code through SMS, they verified by inserting the code and authenticated via Cognito.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One important clarification - Cognito doesn't manage users for you. Cognito leverages public providers (facebook, google, amazon, twitter, an existing external provider...etc.) to generate AWS credentials for whatever user 'signs in'. Additionally, there isn't a native MFA mechanism in Cognito as of now.

With that in mind, it should be possible to do it yourself, however you would need to build some additional mechanism. Say you were trying to log into facebook - the common flow would be to:

1) open up app
2) click sign in button
3) sign in to facebook
4) app validates login with facebook, gets generated token
5) app gives generated token to Cognito, gets an id and credentials.

To catch the login event, you would need some kind of back end that intercepts the login event and has some kind of mapping of login to means of authentication, then once that provider approves the login, you can trigger the auth text/push notification...etc.

Update: this is no longer true, the Cognito User Pools service does manage users for you and allows SMS MFA for authentication.

Comment: What would be the flow for Sign up? I want user to sign up with Mobile number and 2FA instead of signing up with facebook or openid. In which stage I should connect with Cognito?

Comment: If you want to use a mobile number instead of a public provider, you could use developer authenticated identities. On sign up, the app could send creds to your back end. This would register the user and trigger the MFA event. Future sign ins would go from the app to your back end, which would verify them and make a call to the Cognito API GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity. That would give you creds and an id to return to your app for usage. Since Cognito doesn't currently manage users for you, it cannot help you with registration.

Comment: Update: Cognito User Pools is a new branch of Cognito that does manage users for you and allows SMS MFA for user authentication.